# why is django form is updating user object even when the validation fails

Tags: django, forms, validation

I have a django ModelForm based on a custom user model called `CustomUser`.  The email field in my CustomUser is set to unique so that emails don't get reused under different accounts.

In my form when I try to add a duplicate email, django ModelForm fails the validation which is great.  However, it seems to update the email on the user object within that view.  When I try to reference `request.user.email` I get the email that just failed validation instead of the user's email.

To get around this I am refreshing the object from db when the validation fails, but why do I need to?  If the validation failed why is the ModelForm changing my object?

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email_address", unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "This email address is already registered.",
        })


class MemberSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Member Form
    """
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile_pic']


class MemberSettings(View):
    """
    Member settings view
    """
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request):
        form = MemberSettingsForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, 'member/settings_profile.html', {'form': form})    

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def post(self, request):
        form = MemberSettingsForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('member')
        request.user.refresh_from_db()
        return render(request, 'member/settings_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

I am using django 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ModelForm validation is split into two parts. After the form has called its own field and form-level validation methods, it needs to call any model validation methods, including the uniqueness validation. To do that it needs an up-to-date model instance, so it will do that first.

Normally that does not matter, because the thing you are updating is specifically queried for that purpose and not used elsewhere in the view. In your case, refreshing it explicitly from the db sounds like a good solution.